# Passing a pointer to a new object from a different class (C++)

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object

I'm new to classes in C++ (<1 week) so please forgive any misconceptions.

I'll try and generalise this as much as possible for simplicity. My real system has many more functions and variables but I've left them out so I can try and get my point across.

I have 2 classes A and B declared. One of my functions in class A is a getName() function which returns a string. I have dynamically allocated object for class A,  and I believe the specifications of the program require that I pass a pointer to this object into an object for class B, such that the getName() function can be accessed from class B. I am trying to print the name in class B, by using the pointer to class A. The following is my generic code interpretation.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;   


class A
{

public:

    A(string name)
    {
        getName();
    }

    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

private:

    string name;
};


class B
{

public:

    B(A *objectA)
    {
        print();
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << objectA->getName();
    }

private:

    A *objectA;

};


int main()
{
    A *objectA = new A("nameGoesHere");
    B *objectB = new B(objectA);
}
```

This code is very generic but it results in a segmentation fault 11 and I don't understand why. Could someone please explain this to me, or perhaps offer a better approach to passing a pointer to a class, into another class. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `B`'s constructor never saves the `A*` it gets.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the pointer that B constructor receives.

Replace your B constructor with:

```
B(A *objectA) : objectA(objectA)
{
    print();
}
```

To protect your code from segmentation faults, you can also check if the pointer is not null.

You might want do it in B constructor and throw an exception, but that depends of your system requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The member variable `objectA` of class `B` is never initialized, so it's always a dangling pointer. You could use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to initialize it:

```
B(A *p) : objectA(p)
{
    print();
}
```

And the ctor of class `A` has the same problem:

```
A(const string& s) : name(s)
{
    getName();
}
```

Comment: "a danged pointer" I love this, and I think it's often a more accurate label! but the normal term is _dangling pointer_ :) also, I would some side notes: If the OP always needs a valid pointer (not `nullptr`-able), they should use a reference, instead. If still using a pointer, they should change it to `const` if it never needs to change after initialisation.

Comment: @underscore_d Hmm...It's a typo. :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize the class A pointer from class B.

Modify class B constructor to:

```
B(A *objectA_) : objectA(objectA_)
{
    print();
}
```

The "`objectA(objectA_)`" is a initialization list. It initializes your B::*objectA with the pointer you pass as parameter to the constructor.

There's some better explanation [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html).